# Does Covariance inequality still hold when variable is a vector?

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

When I were studying probability theory, I came across the following conclusion ("Covariance inequality"):

> If $x$ and $y$ are two random variable (scalar), the covariance of $x$
> and $y$ is: $$ \rm{Cov}(x, y) =
> > \mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x])(y-\mathbb{E}[y])]=\mathbb{E}[xy]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y].
> > $$ Here $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ means math expectation, and note that
> $\rm{Var}(x)=\mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x] )^2]$ we have: $$
> (\rm{Cov}(x,y))^2 \le \rm{Var}(x) \rm{Var}(y). $$

For a proof of this inequality, refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830231/how-to-prove-the-covariance-inequality-for-discrete-random-variables). However, I am confused if $\bf{X}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $\bf{y}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, does the following inequality still hold?
$$
||\mathbb{E}[\bf{X}\bf{y}]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[\bf{y}]||^2_2 \le ||X-\mathbb{E}[\bf{X}]||^2_F ||\bf{y}-\mathbb{E}[y]||^2_2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - this follows pretty simply from Cauchy-Schwarz.
Taking $X$ and $y$ to be mean zero, and $X_i$ to be the rows of $X$,
\begin{align*}
\lVert\mathbf{E} Xy\rVert^2
= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}( X_i^{\mathrm{T}} y)^2
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}\lVert X_i\rVert^2 \mathbf{E}\lVert y\rVert^2
= \mathbf{E}\lVert X\rVert_F^2 \mathbf{E}\lVert y \rVert^2.
\end{align*}

For non-centered $X$ and $y$, we apply this to
$$
\lVert \mathbf{E} Xy - \mathbf{E} X\, \mathbf{E}y\rVert^2
= \lVert\mathbf{E}(X - \mathbf{E}X)(y - \mathbf{E}y)\rVert^2
\leq \mathbf{E}\lVert X - \mathbf{E}X \rVert_F^2 \mathbf{E}\lVert y - \mathbf{E}y \rVert^2.
$$

Comment: Hi @Damian Pavlyshyn, thank you very much for your kind answer. But I'm sorry that due to my negligence, I got the question wrong, and in order to respect your work, I have submit a new question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775683/does-covariance-inequality-still-hold-when-variable-contain-vector-and-matrix