# Does Covariance inequality still hold when variable contain vector and matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

When I were studying probability theory, I came across the following conclusion ("Covariance inequality"):

> If $x$ and $y$ are two random variable (scalar), the covariance of $x$
> and $y$ is: $$ \rm{Cov}(x, y) =
> \mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x])(y-\mathbb{E}[y])]=\mathbb{E}[xy]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y].
> $$ Here $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ means math expectation, and note that
> $\rm{Var}(x)=\mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x] )^2]$ we have: $$
> (\rm{Cov}(x,y))^2 \le \rm{Var}(x) \rm{Var}(y). $$

For a proof of this inequality, refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830231/how-to-prove-the-covariance-inequality-for-discrete-random-variables). However, I am confused if $\bf{X}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $\bf{y}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, does the following inequality still hold?
$$
\mathbb{E}[||\bf{X}\bf{y}-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[\bf{y}]||^2_2] \le \mathbb{E}[||X-\mathbb{E}[\bf{X}]||^2_F] \mathbb{E}[||\bf{y}-\mathbb{E}[y]||^2_2]
$$

The above inequality is very similar to "Covariance inequality", but somewhat different. Besides, here it is not clear here whether $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{y}$ are independent, that is, we have no way of determining whether $\mathbb{E}[\bf{X}\bf{y}]$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}[\bf{X}]\mathbb{E}[\bf{y}]$.

**Note:** I'm sorry that due to my negligence, I asked a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775627/does-covariance-inequality-still-hold-when-variable-is-a-vector/4775640#4775640), but actually what I really want to ask is the above question. In order to respect the reply of @Damian Pavlyshyn, I submit this new question. Thank you very much @Damian Pavlyshyn.